# hiding an enum constant

Tags: java, api

I'm exposing an enumeration as a guide for traversing a tree-structure in preorder (an iterator uses these enum constants to decide how to traverse the tree):

```
/**
 * The result type of an {@link IVisitor} implementation.
 * 
 * @author Johannes Lichtenberger, University of Konstanz
 */
public enum EVisitResult {
  /** Continue without visiting the siblings of this node. */
  SKIPSIBLINGS,

  /** Continue without visiting the descendants of this node. */
  SKIPSUBTREE,

  /** Continue traversal. */
  CONTINUE,

  /** Terminate traversal. */
  TERMINATE,

  /** Pop from the right sibling stack. */
  SKIPSUBTREEPOPSTACK
}
```

However the last enum constant is only used for an internal visitor and shouldn't ever be used from a user using the public API. Any ideas how I can hide "SKIPSUBTREEPOPSTACK"?

Comment: Peter's answer is probably the simplest approach to do this. But my first instinct would be to see if there's a way to refactor your code to avoid the need for a private enum value.

Comment: Back then I really thought about adding the constant, but it's the only way the iterator/iterable works while removing subtrees (and possibly even merge adjacent TextNodes after a removal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you can do is document that it shouldn't be used.

An alternative is to use an interface

```
public interface EVisitResult {
}

public enum PublicEVisitResult implements EVisitResult {
  /** Continue without visiting the siblings of this node. */
  SKIPSIBLINGS,

  /** Continue without visiting the descendants of this node. */
  SKIPSUBTREE,

  /** Continue traversal. */
  CONTINUE,

  /** Terminate traversal. */
  TERMINATE,
}

enum LocalEVisitResult implements EVisitResult {
  /** Pop from the right sibling stack. */
  SKIPSUBTREEPOPSTACK
}
```

Comment: yes, just thought about this "extensible enum" approach. Hm, I think nobody using the public API will ever get the idea to implement the interface (hopefully ;-)) :D

Comment: Or you could make the value @Deprecated

Comment: I've just changed the code, but hm, I tend to revert my changes and simply document that the value shouldn't be used. Whatever, what do you think? In both cases I need to document that either the value shouldn't be used or that only the "EVisitResult"-enum is supported. Hmm.

Comment: You can also use a special character such a `$` or `_` to show them as special ids  There are actually lots of these odd ones if you really paranoid e.g. including invisible characters :D

Comment: Hm, I will stick to the interface approach, as this is just a special axis which is capable of using the return types of a visitor (for specific node types). However in the future I might come up with further use cases whereas I need other semantics of the return type :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want enum both for public API and internal implementation, you can have 2 enums

```
private enum InternalFoo
    foo1
    foo2
    foox

private void doFoo(InternalFoo foo)
    switch(foo)
        case foo1
        ...


-----


public enum Foo
    foo1(InternalFoo.foo1)
    foo2(InternalFoo.foo2)
    // no foox

    InternalFoo internal;
    Foo(InternalFoo internal){ this.internal=internal; }

public void doFoo(Foo foo)
    doFoo(foo.internal);
```